# How Do I Join Tables to Return a Specific Number of People Per Team Who Fit Certain Criteria?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

This is a pretty specific one:

I have two tables (`t1` and `t2`) -- `t1` is my all-person table, where everybody in my database and all their data is housed, and `t2` is my much smaller table of people who are actually going to do the work of talking to the people in `t1`.

As you can see in this sample **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eda85/7)**, the people in `t1` each have specific criteria assigned to them (age, rating, and team). My end-result will hopefully be: for every one worker in `t2`, the query will return **2** specific people from `t1` if their teams match (the idea behind this is that I'm matching the workers in `t2` to the person they're going to talk to in `t1` based on their team).

But what makes it trickier is that there are two more sets of criteria that I want the query to satisfy also:

1. Only return people from `t1` if their age is in between 30 and 60 (everybody outside of those age-ranges should be ignored) --
2. *And* if there's more than two people that fit the above criteria, return the ones with the best rating first. (For example, if there are four people on a team and we only need two -- so the query should return the two with the best ratings, which would be whichever ratings closer to 100.)

The final thing that is difficult to wrap my head around is that there are multiple workers per team as well -- so if there's two `t2` workers on 'Team A', the query should return four distinct `t1` people on Team A: two attached to one worker and two attached to another (and like I said above, they should be the four best rated people [though it doesn't matter which two people goes to which worker).

My hopeful output will look something like the following for all teams:

```
ID (t1)   Person (t1)   Team (t1)   Worker (t2)
539184    Smith, Jane   Team A      Smith, Bob
539186    Smith, Jim    Team A      Smith, Bob
537141    Smith, Danny  Team A      Smith, Bill
537162    Smith, James  Team A      Smith, Bill
Etc.
```

In reality, I'm doing something similar to this with tens of thousands of records -- which is why this is the only way I can imagine doing it, but I barely even know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'll add any additional information that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL fiddle did not work.  But still going ahead with the query format :)

```
SET @rank:=1, @curr =  0;    

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT @rank := if(@curr = t1.id,  @rank+1, 1 ) as rank,@curr := t1.id as curr, <field_list>
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
WHERE t2.age BETWEEN 30 AND 60 < AND "whatever">
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.ranking desc
) t WHERE rank <= 2 ;
```

replace with fields you want to select like name, id, gender
< AND "whatever"> replace with all conditions you have like "ranking > 10 " etc

Comment: Here's an updated SQL fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eda85/7) with the way I attempted to get your query to work. I removed "<field_list>" because I didn't know what that was doing, as well as "<AND "whatever">", and fixed some of the t1/t2 swaps. The way the code is written now in the fiddle returns zero records, but it gives no error. Part of the problem is likely that you're joining `t1` and `t2` on their respective IDs -- but workers from `t2` might not necessarily be in the `t1` people table. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this still doesn't seem to be working -- if you have a chance to jump in the SQL Fiddle in the comment above and shoot something back, that'd be great.

Comment: Please try to understand the query. How do you relate the two tables ? t1.id=t2.id doesnot match anything. Its not problem with query logic, make necessary changes for yourself. When I joined with "t1.LastName = t2.LastName" it gives output

Comment: I was assuming that there would be some sort of a JOIN on team because those are what the two tables share. The query should essentially look through `t2` for how many people are on each team, and then return the best two people from `t1` based on that.